# i am trying to add image using but it is showing image of null in node js

Tags: html, css, node.js, image, post

i am trying to add product in this and validating using expressvalidator and adding a image in same form but i am having a issue check my code here please help.

```
router.post('/add-product', (req,res) => {
    // if req.files.image is undefined  it will be req.files.image.name  else empty string.
    let imageFile = typeof req.files.image !== "undefined" ? req.files.image.name : "";
    console.log(typeof imageFile);

    req.checkBody('title', 'Title must have a value.').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('desc', 'desc must have a value').notEmpty();
    req.checkBody('price', 'price must have a value').isDecimal();
    req.checkBody('image', 'you must have a image').isImage(imageFile); //isImage is from app.js

    var title = req.body.title;
    var slug = title.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();

    var desc = req.body.desc;
    var price = req.body.price;
    var category = req.body.category;


    var errors = req.validationErrors();
    if (errors) {
        Category.find(function(err, categories) {
            res.render('admin/add_product', {
                errors: errors,
                title: title,
                desc: desc,
                categories: categories,
                price: price
            });
        });
    } else {
        Product.findOne({ slug: slug }, function(err, product) {
            if (product) {
                req.flash('danger', 'product title exist');
                Category.find(function(err, categories) {
                    res.render('admin/add_product', {
                        title: title,
                        desc: desc,
                        categories: categories,
                        price: price
                    });
                });
            } else {
                //converting the string value of price to float
                var price2 = parseFloat(price).toFixed(2);
                var product = new Product({
                    title: title,
                    slug: slug,
                    desc: desc,
                    price: price2,
                    category: category,
                    image: imageFile


                });
                console.log(price)
                console.log(price2)
                console.log(imageFile)

                product.save(function(err) {
                    console.log('yaha hai');
                    if (err)
                        return console.log(err)
                    console.log('idhr chk1');


                    mkdirp('public/product_images/' + product._id, function(err) {
                        return console.log(err);
                    });

                    mkdirp('public/product_images/' + product._id + '/gallery', function(err) {
                        return console.log(err);
                    });
                    mkdirp('public/product_images/' + product._id + '/gallery/thums', function(err) {
                        return console.log(err);
                    });

                    if (imageFile != "") {
                        var productImage = req.files.image;
                        var path = 'public/product_images/' + product._id + '/' + imageFile;

                        productImage.mv(path, function(err) {
                            return console.log(err);
                        })
                    }
                    req.flash('success', 'page added');
                    res.redirect('/admin/products');

                });
            }
        })
    }
})
```

i feel here is the main problem

```
 let imageFile = typeof req.files.image !== "undefined" ? req.files.image.name : "";
```

i am trying to add product in this and validating using expressvalidator and adding a image in same form but i am having a issue check my code here please help.
i am creating a e-commerce website as a project so please help i am stuck here from last 2 days here is the error of code TypeError: Cannot read property 'image' of null.